# How to draw a smooth U with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a smooth U like the one from the Ubuntu titling font:

[image]

I need to draw this because I want to have a shape similar to the "U" letter but with a larger space between the vertical bars of the "U".

What approach should I use to do this with TikZ? At the moment I have this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line join=round,line cap=round,thick](0,.3)to[bend right=20](0,0)to[bend right=45](.2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

but it does not look very nice. It seems I can't make the vertical part join the horizontal part in a smooth way.

Comment: should it look like a horse shoe or just a wider U?

Comment: just a wider U.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try with an `arc`

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line join=round,line cap=round,thick](0,1)--++(0,-.5) arc[start angle=180, end angle=360, radius=0.5]--++(0,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]